# dynamic, conditioned drupal webforms select options

Tags: drupal, webforms, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-webform

i'm a beginner in drupal and i'm working on a project for a hospital, and i'm stuck in some issues that i didn't find any answers to, so there is my problem :-

---

**What i've done**
-created roles(doctor, patient, manager).
-created taxonomy vocabulary (specialty) that contains (medical specialties as terms) .. e.g.(eye dept., surgery dept., ..etc).
-i installed modules (views, webforms, webforms term options) to create an online medical appointments booking form that accepts (name, mobile, specialty, doctor, date, time).
-for the specialty field i added an automatic webform term options take the values from the taxonomy vocabulary.
**What i want to do**
-i want to assign doctors to a specific specialty, e.g.: doctor_x & doctor_y are working in eye dept. -- doctor_a & doctor_b are working in surgery -- and so on!
-then when the patient choose eye dept. in the form -> the doctor option is filled with the doctors that work in this dept. 
-and when the patient select the same time & date for the same doctor show a message (this appointment is already reserved please choose another one!).
-and i want to create a views page of the submissions of every doctor that appears on his account (no one can see it except him) arranged and separated by day.

---

thanks in advance,
and sorry about my bad english.

Comment: Hi Sayed, this may be a bit too broad for Stack Overflow; there is a specialized Drupal Stack Exchange site: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ that may be able to help you if nothing comes from it here. You clearly are on a good path to asking good, detailed questions already; just one thing, do make sure capitalize the "I" in "I am" and so on. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Pekka 웃, I'll keep your notes in my mind.